# Jquery - appending after re-registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-append

On this script I have drag and drop fieldsets (left menu - top).  Drag multiple fieldsets into the right "working area".  In those fieldsets is an area for dropping Fields (of which I have one, left menu - bottom).  Drop "Field One" into any of the dropped Fieldset (under the line in the "Drop Fields Here" area) in the working area.

I want to then move that Field One from the Fieldset I dropped it into and into the other Fieldset in the working area.  I have got the Field One draggable but I cannot get it to append to the new Fieldset.

I am not wanting to delete the Field and replace it with another clone from the left menu.  I am new to jquery so my code may be a bit messy.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Jsfiddle and code below.

I believe the code issue is between line 21-29...but I am not sure.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/humphrey_brent/hdb0epx6/231/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var fs_count = 0;
$("#drop-area").droppable({
accept: '.ui-draggable:not(.draggableField , .activeField)',
drop: function(event, ui) {
    fs_count++;
  var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
  clone.addClass('.connectedSortable')
  // clone.removeClass('.ui-draggable');
  if (clone.hasClass('dropped')) {
        return false;
    }
    clone.addClass('.connectedSortable').addClass('dropped').attr('id', 'fs_' + fs_count);
  $(this).append(clone);
  var fs_class = clone.attr('class');
  alert('You added a field with class ' + fs_class);      
  var fieldsDroppable = $('#drop-area .ui-draggable:last-child .fieldDroppable');
  fieldsDroppable.droppable({
  accept: '.draggableField , .activeField',
      drop: function(event, ui) {          
          var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();  
          if (clone.hasClass('draggableField')) {  // If else to prevent clones reproducing in Fieldsets when moving from original Fieldset.
          clone.removeClass('ui-draggable , draggableField').addClass('activeField');
          $(this).append(clone);
                    }
                        else {
          // Append the div here? 
          }             
          var cloneClass = clone.attr('class');  // Temporary varialble for develpoment alert below
          alert('you dropped a field' + cloneClass);  // Temporary for development only

                        // Below re-register the "field" with jquery....not sure this is entirely correct.
          var fieldsDraggable = $('#drop-area .ui-draggable .fieldDroppable .activeField');
                fieldsDraggable.draggable();              
      }});
}  });
$(".fieldDroppable").droppable({
accept: '.draggableField , .activeField',
drop: function(event, ui) {
  var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
  $(this).append(clone);
}
  });
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
opacity: 1.0,
helper: 'clone',
revert: 'invalid'
});
$(".draggableField").draggable({
opacity: 1.0,
helper: 'clone',
revert: 'false'
});  
$(".activeField").draggable();
$("#drop-area").sortable({ 
handle: '.drag-handle',
update: function () { //triggered when sorting stopped
var dataAuto = $("#drop-area").sortable("serialize", {
        key: "za",
        attribute: "id",
    });
        alert(dataAuto);  
}
});
$("#drop-area").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: So to replicate, 1) Drag a fieldset into work space, 2) drag a 2nd field set into work space, 3) drag a field into a field set, 4) drag the same field from field set to field set right?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly that.

Comment: Ok, what about this: `if (clone.hasClass('draggableField')) { // If else to prevent clones moving from Fieldset to Fieldset` Your code is written to prevent those steps above.

Comment: That is a poorly written comment on my part.  I am fixing that now.  It is to prevent clones from being created of the dropped Field.  The original drop (into a Fieldset) is a clone of the left menu.  After that drop it needs to stop cloning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a lot of work to do here, yet you can get over this hurdle like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6trmrfoo/32/

Basically, you want to assign a new `.droppable()` to a specific element in the field set when it is added to the `#drop-area`. I would advise using a function as you will do this a multitude of times.

You can also make use of `.data()` to store a `source` value along with the draggable elements. I only did this for fields since that was the only pace it seemed like it was needed. You can updated this once it's dropped into a fieldset so that future drag-n-drop operations can be handled properly, we don't want to clone the object we move it.

To move it, consider using `.detach()`. It'll detach the element from the current parent and can be used in chain to append or move into memory as a variable. Similar to `.clone()` just we're manipulating the actual object. `.clone()` is to "Copy & Paste" as `.detach()` is to "Cut & Paste".

**JavaScript**

```
 $(function() {
   var fs_count = 0;

   function makeFieldTarget($fs) {
     $fs.droppable({
       accept: '.draggableField, .activeField',
       drop: function(event, ui) {
         var clone, cloneClass;
         if (ui.draggable.data("source") == "sidebar") {
           clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
           clone.removeClass('draggableField').addClass('activeField');
           $(this).append(clone);
           cloneClass = clone.attr('class');
           console.log('DROPFIELD - you dropped a field from the side bar: ' + cloneClass);
           clone.data("source", "fieldset").draggable({
             zIndex: 1000
           });
         }
         if (ui.draggable.data("source") == "fieldset") {
           clone = ui.draggable;
           clone.detach().attr("style", "").appendTo($(this));
           cloneClass = clone.attr('class');
           console.log('DROPFIELD - you dropped a field from a Field set: ' + cloneClass);
         }
       }
     });
   }


   $("#drop-area").droppable({
     accept: '.ui-draggable:not(.draggableField, .activeField)',
     drop: function(event, ui) {
       fs_count++;
       var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
       clone.addClass('connectedSortable');
       if (clone.hasClass('dropped')) {
         return false;
       }
       clone.addClass('connectedSortable dropped').attr('id', 'fs_' + fs_count);
       $(this).append(clone);
       var fs_class = clone.attr('class');
       console.log('DROPAREA - You added a field with class ' + fs_class);
       makeFieldTarget(clone.find(".fieldDroppable"));
       $("#drop-area").sortable("refresh");
     }
   });

   $(".ui-draggable").draggable({
     opacity: 1.0,
     helper: 'clone',
     revert: 'invalid'
   });

   $(".draggableField").data("source", "sidebar").draggable({
     opacity: 1.0,
     helper: 'clone',
     revert: 'false',
     zIndex: 1000
   });

   $("#drop-area").sortable({
     handle: '.drag-handle',
     placeholder: "drop-place-holder",
     items: ">div.dropped",
     update: function() { //triggered when sorting stopped
       var dataAuto = $("#drop-area").sortable("serialize", {
         key: "za",
         attribute: "id",
       });
       alert(dataAuto);
     }
   });

   $("#drop-area").disableSelection();

 });
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you for explaining it as well.  I am now trying to attach an attribute to the field when dropped into the fieldset.  I want to make an attribute "parent" or something that will be equal to the 'id' of the fieldset the field was dropped into.

Comment: Twisty, you solved my isssue so effortlessly I thought you might have a really quick resolution to my next issue on this project.  If you have time, it is here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709913/jquery-serializing-drop-and-down-group-with-existing-element